# displaying content that includes shortcodes within an echo

Tags: php, shortcode

I have created a custom comment system, when people enter in video shortcodes it doesn't display the video but just echo's out the shortcode.

I understand the do_shortcode(); command but the comments can contain comments as well as shortcodes.

Is there a best practice around having the shortscodes work?

Thanks

-Chalkie

edit this is my function:

```
function display_match_comments() {
    global $current_user; wp_get_current_user();
    global $match_id;
    global $wpdb;
    global $comment_success; 
    echo '<div class="latest_results" style="background:#ffffff; text-align:left !important;"">';
    echo '<h6 style="text-align:center !important;">User Comments and Pictures';
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo ' <a href="#add_comment">Add Comment</a>';
    }
    echo '</h6>';
    $content_size = 'one_half';
    $table_name = 'wp_match_comments';
    $row2 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE comment_gameid = $match_id AND comment_moderation = '1'");
    if(!$row2) { echo 'No Comments Found</span>'; }
    foreach($row2 as $row2) { 
            if(!$content_size){ $content_size = "one_half"; }
            echo '<div class="'.$content_size.'">';
            echo '<div class="latest_results" style="background:#ffffff;">';
            echo '<h6><a href="https://www.husupporters.club/forums/users/'.$row2->comment_name.'">'.$row2->comment_name.'</a></h6>';
            $comment_content = stripslashes_deep($row2->comment_content);
echo '<span>'.$comment_content.'<br>';
            $react_id = $row2->id. '_' .$match_id;
            echo do_shortcode('[reactions id="'.$react_id.'"]');
            echo '</span><br>';
            $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode = '<span><a href="https://www.husupporters.club/wp-admin/admin.php?page=match_comments&id='.$row2->id.'" class="gamedetail">Manage Comment</a></span>';
            echo do_shortcode( '[UAS_role roles="administrator, moderator"]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/UAS_role]' );
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            if ($content_size == "one_half") { $content_size = "one_half last_column"; goto skip2; }else{ $content_size = "one_half"; goto skip2; }
            skip2:
        }
    echo '<div id="add_comment" class="latest_results" style="background:#ffffff; text-align:left !important;"">';
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<h6 style="text-align:center !important;">Add your own comment and 
pictures below</h6>';
    if(get_query_var( 'success' ) != 'yes') { 
     ?>
<form method="POST"  action="<?php the_permalink(); echo $match_id; ?>?success=yes">
    <?php wp_editor($comment_content,"comment_content", array('textarea_rows'=>12, 'editor_class'=>'comment_content_class')); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_name" value="<?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_gameid" value="<?php echo $match_id; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitComment" value="submit" />
    </form>
<?php
    }
$default_comment = array(
            'comment_name' => '',
            'comment_content' => '',
            'comment_moderation' => '0',
            'comment_gameid' => '',
        );
$item = shortcode_atts( $default_comment, $_REQUEST );
if($_POST['submitComment']) { 
       $wpdb->prepare($wpdb->insert( $table_name, $item ));
}
if(get_query_var( 'success' ) == 'yes') { echo '<span>Your comment has been sent for approval</span><br>'; }
}else{
    echo '<h6 style="text-align:center !important;"> you must be <a href="https://www.husupporters.club/login-register/">logged in</a> 
    to comment</h6>';
}
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This is the part that displays the comment

```
$comment_content = stripslashes_deep($row2->comment_content);
echo '<span>'.$comment_content.'<br>';
```

Within that someone could use the [video] shortcode but it displays the shortcode text not a video.

Comment: Include the code, maybe someone will be able to help if they can see what's actually happening.

Comment: We can't help you without checking your code so add the code here.

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 2):

If some of your comments will contain shortcodes and some won't, there's no harm in running them all through [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/). If the content has no shortcodes in it, it will simply be returned, and if it *does* contain shortcodes, they'll be parsed and the content returned.

So you should be able to change

```
echo '<span>'.$comment_content.'<br>';
```

to

```
echo do_shortcode( '<span>'.$comment_content.'<br>' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not realise you can have non shortcode data within the do_shortcode function. 1000 kudos to you good sir!